# Laravel not reading array index in blade syntax

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.6

I have an multidimensional array that I pass to a view in laravel.  This array is used to output data to the view using blade syntax.  But when I try to access a key in a `@foreach` loop I receive an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` .
When I output the same array index within `php` tags the line before the `@foreach ()` loop, there is no error.
Can someone please give me a clue to why this would happen?

array var_dumped : `$item['all']`

```
@php
    echo var_dump($item['all']);
    die();
@endphp
```

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=22)
      'withdraw_prod' => int 0
      'class_id' => int 10
      'optional' => int 0
      'extra' => int 0
      'stage' => string 'NA' (length=2)
      'pest' => string 'NA' (length=2)
      'product' => string 'Monitering' (length=10)
      'description' => null
      'active' => null
      'class' => string 'Ander' (length=5)
      'rac_code' => null
      'htwoo' => string '0' (length=1)
      'prod_ha' => string '2.98' (length=4)
      'kgl_ha' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      'hundred_met' => null
      'total' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      'cost_kgl' => null
      'cost_total' => null
      'heading' => null
      'header' => int 0
      'hex' => null
      'is_na' => boolean true
```

Code next line that gives error:

```
@foreach ($item['all'] as $k => $spray)
```

Some LOG output:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $item['all']; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $k => $spray): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

**Laravel 5.6.39**

Edit:
I am trying to output data to a view that is generating a pdf from controller:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('direct.tory.here.is.pdf', compact('program', 'taboo', 'colour', 'footnotes'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
```

The loops in the view is:

```
@foreach ($program as $key => $item)
    @if(!in_array($key, $taboo))
         @php
             $cnt = 0;
             $extra_row = 0;
             //echo var_dump($item['all']);
         @endphp
         @foreach ($item['all'] as $k => $spray)
              @php
                  // for in case array dimensions differ
                  $sprays = (array_key_exists(0, $spray)) ? $spray[0] : $spray;
                      if(!empty($sprays['description'])) {
                         $extra_row++;
                       }
                @endphp
          @endforeach
    @endif
    @php
         $col++;
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

**Solved it**
This is a bit embarrassing, but I had created an array with taboo keys that filtered out non array values from my main array `$program`.  For testing two months ago an extra dummy key => value that contained an integer was added for testing, but was never added to the taboo list.  This dummy integer value was slipping through causing the `@foreach` loop not being able to iterate over the `$item['all']` which did not exist for that array index.
Thank you for your input all who commented.

Comment: Maybe remove the `die()`? What does `{{ dd($item['all']) }}` output?

Comment: It outputs the same array 
`
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:22 [▼
    "withdraw_prod" => 0
    "class_id" => 10
    "optional" => 0
    "extra" => 0
    "stage" => "NA"
    "pest" => "NA"
    "product" => "Monitering"
    "description" => null
    "active" => null
    "class" => "Ander"
    "rac_code" => null
    "htwoo" => "0"
    "prod_ha" => "2.98"
    "kgl_ha" => "0.0000"
    "hundred_met" => null
    "total" => "0.0000"
    "cost_kgl" => null
    "cost_total" => null
    "heading" => null
    "header" => 0
    "hex" => null
    "is_na" => true
  ]
]`

Comment: When you say *When I output the same array index within php tags the line before the @foreach () loop, there is no error* do you mean the error in the `@foreach` goes away by the act of outputting something before it?

Comment: @apokryfos No, I mean that outputting the array index before the `@foreach` loop causes no error (therefore the index exists as an array), but that as soon as I try to access the array index in the `@foreach` loop I receive an error.

Comment: Based on the data you shared in your comment, there is not any "all" key inside your array.

Comment: Is this the only `foreach` you have in your blade file?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi What do you mean? Outputting `{{ dd($item['all']) }}`, as shown in my first comment gives an array of two dimension.  I am trying to iterate through the array `$item['all]`  with `@foreach`.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry I mean no. It is a nested `@foreach`.

Comment: Ok. Please go ahead and put your code that is inside your foreach.

Comment: if you replace the `@foreach ($item['all'] as $k => $spray)` with `<?php foreach ($item['all'] as $k => $spray): ?>` does it work or still the same?

Comment: @apokryfos I still receive same error. I will post complete nested loop as suggested by @~AhmadKarimi.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi added nested loop to question.

Comment: @apokryfos added nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created an array with taboo keys that filtered out non array values from my main array `$program`. For testing two months ago an extra dummy `key => value` that contained an integer was added for testing, but was never added to the taboo list. This dummy integer value was slipping through causing the `@foreach` loop not being able to iterate over the `$item['all']` which did not exist for that array index.

So solution is oversight and not `type checking` before using a value.